# Redis clustering minimum nodes AWS Elasticache

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, redis-cluster, amazon-elasticache

This one should be fairly simple for someone who understands more than me! I have a Redis cluster set up with multi availability zone (Multi-AZ) on AWS, using Elasticache.

I set up with 3 shards, and 3 nodes on each shard (9 total nodes). This is the recommended minimum. I read in another article that `Specifically, in the case of minimal cluster configuration, you'll want 3 masters to ensure the cluster's availability in case of a partition, or else you won't be able to agree on majority.`

Does that mean the minimum on AWS should be indeed a total of 9 nodes? That's 3 masters and 6 slaves (as 1 master, 2 slaves per shard), or can one get away with 1 shard, with 1 master and 2 slaves? (for a total of 3 nodes)

We're running a growing business that is rapidly expanding, so want to at least be covered.

I'd like to keep costs down, and running 9 nodes on a t2.micro is acceptable, but running 9 nodes on a t2.medium starts to get expensive!

Thanks